# Count unique users in wtmp file

Tags: uniq, wtmp

I am struggling to count the unique users in the wtmp file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
uniqueUsers=$(last | uniq -c | wc -l)

echo "There were '$uniqueUsers' unique users logged on"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: this looks like a good start. what, exactly, are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2):

The `last` command gives multi-column output; you should extract just the first column (using `awk` or `cut`), and sort the data so that `uniq` can do its job.  Using both `uniq -c` and `wc -l` is redundant (choose one):

```
uniqueUsers=$(last |cut -f1 -d ' ' | grep -v -e '^\(\|reboot\|wtmp\)$' |sort -u | wc -l)
```

Comment: sure - will improve it :-)

Answer (score 1):

My stab, a little shorter (since I prefer awk over cut):

```
uniqueUsers=$(last | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u | grep -vE 'reboot|wtmp|^$'| wc -l)
```

Comment: The awk command uses more characters than the cut.  Also, without anchoring, the grep could pick up false matches.  (I could have eliminated the backslashes using the ERE option of course, but don't cut/paste from people's comments when answering questions).

Answer (score 0):

ignore the blank lines, wtmp and reboot.

```
last | awk '!a[$1]++&&$1!~/reboot|wtmp|^$/' | wc -l
```